# Prove that $\||A|^{1/2}V|A|^{1/2}\|\leq \|A\|.$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\|\cdot\|)$.

For $A \equiv V|A|$ the canonical polar decomposition of $A\in \mathcal{B}(F)$, we let $\tilde{A}:=|A|^{1/2}V|A|^{1/2}$. Here $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$ and $V$ is a partial isometry.

> I want to prove that
>   $$\|\tilde{A}\|\leq \|A\|.$$

We have
$$\|\tilde{A}\|=\sup\{\||A|^{1/2}V|A|^{1/2}x\|: x\in F, \|x\|=1 \}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\|A^* A\| = \|A\|^2$ (the $C^* $ identity), and $|A|$ is the positive semidefinite square root of $A^* A$ so (using the spectral theorem) $\||A|\| = \|A\|$ and $\||A|^{1/2}\| = \|A\|^{1/2}$.  Then 
$$ \|\tilde{A}\| \le \||A|^{1/2}\| \|V\| \||A|^{1/2}\| = \|A\|$$

Comment: Please is this $\||A|^{1/2}\| = \|A\|^{1/2}$ equality? I don't see why it holds.

Comment: I hope to explain me why the last equality holds. Thanks

Comment: Suppose $X$ is hermitian.  For any continuous function $f$, the eigenvalues of $f(X)$ are $f(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ the eigenvalues of $X$, and $\|f(X)\|$ is the maximum of $|f(\lambda)|$ for those eigenvalues.  Apply that to $X = A^* A$ with $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$.

Comment: @Robert: you don't really need functional calculus. It follows directly from the C$^*$-identity. I have no idea why they downvoted you.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Could you please explain me your idea Professor Thanks a lot.

Comment: $$\|\,|A|\,\|^2=\|\,|A|^2\|=\|A^*A\|=\|A\|^2. $$ Then $$\|\,|A|^{1/2}\|^2=\|(|A|^{1/2})^2\|=\|\,|A|\,\|=\|A\|. $$